# command option confusion in curl on Linux

Tags: linux, curl

Wondering what is the function of `@` sign? Here is an example command,

```
curl -w "@curl-format.txt" -o /dev/null -s "http://wordpress.com/"
```

Here are more related backgrounds,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215389/how-do-i-measure-request-and-response-times-at-once-using-curl

Comment: @ symbol at the start of a value  usually means "read the real value from the named file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it just means read the format from the named file.

from the manual:

> ```
>   -w, --write-out <format>
>     Defines  what  to  display on stdout after a completed
> and successful operation. The format is a string that may contain
> plain text mixed with any number of variables. The string can be 
> specified as "string", to get read from a particular file you
> specify it "@filename" and to tell curl to read the format from
>           stdin you write "@-".
> ```

using @ like this is fairly common, curl uses it in several places, other commands do too.

Comment: Thanks user313114, vote up and mark your reply as answer. I tried to use curl -h, but cannot find the information you posted, where do you find the information posted? :)